# How to output x amount of outputs in grep and skipping repeating ones

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, head

So I'm having trouble with a quick shell script I'm currently making, the script consist of putting a youtube channels name, then finding there 5 newest videos.

I'm using the youtube front-end "vid.puffyan.us" to do this.

So when grepping for the 5 videos, due to how the sites html is, the same videos id repeats 3 times, is there any way to skip these, and output 5 different id's?

My current code is:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

query=$(printf '%s' "$*" | tr ' ' '+')
channel=$(curl -s "https://vid.puffyan.us/search?q=$query" | grep -Eo "channel/.{24}" | head -n 1)

if [ -z "$query" ]
then
    echo "blank input!"
else
    curl -s "https://vid.puffyan.us/$channel" | grep -Eo "watch\?v=.{11}" | head -n 5
fi
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title, accepting an answer when you can is enough

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix from [mdmay74](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/391285/mdmay74) was to just pipe the output through `uniq`, and then through `head`.

example:

```bsh
curl -s "https://vid.puffyan.us/$channel" | grep -Eo "watch\?v=.{11}" | uniq | head -n 5
```

Comment: Unless the output from curl is sorted, you should probably use `sort` before `uniq`